# XSLT key statement return a group and i can not separate the result

Tags: xml, xslt-1.0

I have a problem and I need you're help with the following XML example.

```
<A>
<B Name="Alpha"> 
    <C>
        <D>
            <E Nr="1" Wert="A"/>
            <E Nr="2" Wert="B"/>
            <E Nr="3" Wert="C"/>
            <E Nr="4" Wert="D"/>
        </D>
        <F Name="Fo" E_Nr="3"/>
    </C>
</B>
<B Name="Beta">
    <C>
        <D>
            <E Nr="1" Wert="E"/>
            <E Nr="2" Wert="F"/>
            <E Nr="3" Wert="G"/>
            <E Nr="4" Wert="H"/>
        </D>
        <F Name="Bar" E_Nr="2"/>
    </C>
</B>
```

The result after a transformation should be the following text.

```
Fo C
Bar F
```

In my XSLT I use the key statement but I get more then one result for the key link.

```
<xsl:key name="test" match="//E" use="@Nr"/>
```

To distinguish the subtrees I want to use the attribute from **B**.
So my result is:

```
Fo C
Bar C
```

But I think it is necessary to use a key because in **D** can be inside thousand of **E** nodes.

Is it possible to solve this problem efficiently with XSLT?

Tanks for you're help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To limit the key to the current `B` element, define it as:

```
<xsl:key name="e" match="E" use="concat(@Nr, '|', generate-id(ancestor::B))" />
```

then call it from the context of `F` as:

```
<xsl:value-of select="key('e', concat(@E_Nr, '|',  generate-id(ancestor::B)))/@Wert"/>
```

---

**Demo**: https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/ehVZvvG